# Accept <br> for new line but filter html tags in php

Tags: php

I want my input or textarea value only accept `<br>` for having new lines

```
$comment = trim($comment);
$comment = stripslashes($comment) ;
```

Although I do want to accept `<br>` for new lines  but I dont want to accept html tags

any suggestion ?

Comment: How come you've got `<br>` tags from a textarea? Who would bother to enter it instead of just pressing Enter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better solution is to allow users to enter new lines in text areas, and translate them to `<br>` tags when you display the text with [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

When you display the text, first encode html entities, then translate the newlines to `<br>` tags. If you use `nl2br` before `htmlspecialchars`, you'll wind up encoding the `<br>` tags as well.

```
echo (nl2br(htmlspecialchars($text));
```

Comment: don't use htmlentities. use htmlspecialchars.

Answer (score 0):

You can allow the text area to take newline characters. Then you can use those as `<br>`s, just replace them after trimming and stripping all tags, or use a tool to display plain text as html.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't be calling stripslashes, unless you're in the middle of building an SQL query.

Comment: oh no. quite the contrary, stripslashes has absolutely nothing to do in the middle of building an SQL query.

Comment: You've got that backwards. If magic quotes are enabled, then slashes will be added to everything by default, so you need to call stripslashes *unless* you're building a SQL query.

Comment: @Josh You've got that backwards. If magic quotes are enabled,  you need to call stripslashes **unconditionally**

Comment: You're right, I was thinking of addslashes. But I wouldn't use stripslashes this way either. If magic quotes is on, you should do it for EVERY get/post/cookie field, before doing anything else.

Answer (score -2):

you can use `strip_tags` which takes `$allowable_tags` as its second parameter:

```
$comment = strip_tags($comment, '<br>');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: you are talking about `strip_tags`, but using `trim` in your example :-)

Comment: jesus you guys are fast at downvoting, I edited it literally within 10 seconds of posting the answer :<

Comment: To let you know, this is well-known XSS vulnerability