# explode an string and html special character filter in php

Tags: php

i have a textarea with ckeditor customized toolbar which user can only select smiley

now i want users can only use smilys and new line function

so if $comment is my raw text output with html tags and i want only smiley and text with new lines appeared in output not other html tags

**sample raw data :**

```
<p>
    this is a sample text</p>
<p>
    <img alt="angry" src="includes/ckeditor/plugins/smiley/images/angry_smile.gif" title="angry" /></p>
<p>
    text for sample</p>
```

**for new line in html :**

```
$comment = nl2br($comment);
```

**but what about showing only smileys ?!**

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, then here is reference, to what you might need: [strip_tags](http://ee.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Here is what I came up with:

```
function smileAndText( $some_text = '' ) {

    if( ! empty( $some_text ) ) {

        $some_text = nl2br( $some_text );

        $some_text = strip_tags( $some_text, '<img><br />' );

    }

    return $some_text;

}
```

Comment: thanks that works but only for showing img not new line  i think i should replace <p> with html entity ? ---- and the other thing is how to specify img tag to only smiley source ?! i mean only smileys allowed to show not other images

Comment: `strip_tags` is extremely vulnerable to XSS attacks, and doesn't obviate the need for you to encode your output with `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities` *before* you run it through `nl2br`.

Answer (score 2):

As I answered in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961780/accept-br-for-new-line-but-filter-html-tags-in-php), encode your output with `htmlspecialchars` and then use `nl2br` to convert new lines to `<br>` tags.

To replace text smilies with graphics, you want a series of regular expressions rather than attempting to explode the string and output it in pieces.

The following should give you some idea:

```
$comment = htmlspecialchars(comment);
$comment = nl2br($comment);

$smilies = array(
  '/\b:\)\b/' => '<img src="smile.gif" />',   // :)
  '/\b:\(\b/' => '<img src="sad.gif" />',     // :(
  '/\b:p\b/'  => '<img src="tongue.gif" />',  // :p
);

$comment = preg_replace(array_keys($smilies), $smilies, $comment);
```

Comment: thanks but as far as i replied to others' answers , i want to able users to use smiley icon and eugene is correct , and the only problem now is how to restrict img tag to only images from this address : includes/ckeditor/plugins/smiley/images/

Comment: @Mac You don't have to if you follow my advice and run your text through `htmlspecialchars` before you do your `nl2br` or smiley conversion.

Comment: but meagar i dont want to replace emotion icon with text emotions , i just need to show icons

Comment: @Mac Then insert custom tags like `[:smile:]` or `[:frown:]`, run the comment through `htmlspecialchars`, and translate your special tags to `<img>` tags. It is fundamentally unsafe to rely on `strip_tags` to remove some tags but not others.

Answer (score 1):

Look at php strip_tags http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php. You could do something like

```
$comment = strip_tags(nl2br($comment),"<br />, #smiley_tag");
```

Comment: Or you could use a regex expression to strip away everything except <br /> and whatever your smiley tags code is.

Comment: `<br />` shouldn't be accepted by `strip_tags` function. You need just `<br>`.

Comment: i want to stip all html tags except img tag that is used for showing smileys  , read my comment on bpeterson76 answer

Comment: so would you mind updating your answer with ereg_replace() ?!

Comment: @Mac `ereg_replace` is deprecated, don't use it. Use the preg_* functions instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do with the smileys, but there is a way to configure CK in the javascript config file to use 
 when the enter key is pressed.  I'd still think about post-process replacing, but that's a good way to make clean code happen on the front end.

Comment: i thought i explained my will compeletly , uh .. just concider im trying to able my users only use smiley and new line  in textarea and strip all other html tags

Comment: Mac, almost seems like it'd be easier (and less overhead) to do a textarea that you code to take smileys....a roll-it-yourself smiley WYSIWYG.  See this: http://www.phorum.org/phorum5/read.php?8,48517